# Why does RestClient.ExecuteAsync<List<T>>() return null for an array-valued JSON response?

Tags: c#, xml, restsharp, rest-client

I need help with the project I am currently working on. Please bare with me, I'm not good at coding specially with c# this is my first attempt.

I have a button the will pull the data from webservice. Saving of data to database will be triggered with the same button. I have manage to display the string via tutorial and now stuck on saving I don't know where I went wrong it keeps on throwing error that **Value cannot be null ** I have provided that error message for your reference and the json output.

This is what I have so far

CIP.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using System.IO;
using RestSharp;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace SAPSO
{
    class CIP
    {
        public class DetailOutput
        {
            public string NAME { get; set; }
            public string ADD { get; set; }
            public string GAP { get; set; }
            public DateTime SDTE { get; set; }
            public DateTime EDTE { get; set; }
        }

        RestClient client;
        RestRequest request;
        
        public CIP()
        {
            client = new RestClient(@"urlpath/");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "pass");
        }

       public List<DetailOutput>
        GetDetailOutputs(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            request = new RestRequest("sap/bc/zcip", Method.Get);
            request.AddParameter("sap-client", "200");
            request.AddParameter("start", "");
            request.AddParameter("end", end.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
            var output = client.ExecuteAsync<List<DetailOutput>>(request);
            var o = output.Result.Data;
            return o;    
        }

        public void ProcessOutput(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            var output = GetDetailOutputs(start, end);

            if (output.Count() < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Null");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
            }

            var xmlPath = new XElement("CIPS",
               from CIPPath in output
               select new XElement("CIP",
                      new XElement("NAME", CIPPath.NAME),
                      new XElement("ADD", CIPPath.ADD),
                      new XElement("GAP", CIPPath.GAP),
                      new XElement("SDTE", CIPPath.SDTE),
                      new XElement("EDTE", CIPPath.EDTE)));
            insertCIP(xmlPath.ToString(), "InsertDetail");

        }

        //insert to db
        int insertCIP(string xml, string strdproc)
        {
            int row = 0;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strdproc))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 3000;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xmldata", xml);
                        con.Open();
                        row = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return row;
        }

    }
}
```

This is my form1.cs

```
void m_oWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _backgroundWorkerThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        SAP svc = new SAP();
        CIP cip = new CIP();
        cip.ProcessOutput(dte_from.Value, dte_to.Value);
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        m_oWorker.Dispose();
        Thread.ResetAbort();
    }
}
```

I use Microsoft sqlserver for my database.

Here is the sample output of the webservice:

```
[{"NAME":"FOLDERNME","ADD":"0000000376_0000000385","GAP":"GP\\ADVNAME\\ADVNME2, INC","SDTE ":"0000-00-00","EDTE  ":"0000-00-00"}]
```

And this is the error I'm getting.

> System.ArgumentNullException   HResult=0x80004003   Message=Value
> cannot be null. Parameter name: source   Source=System.Core
> StackTrace:    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1
> source)    at SAPSO.CIP.ProcessOutput(DateTime start, DateTime end) in
> C:\prjname\trunk\GET\SAPSO\CIP.cs:line 58    at
> SAPSO.Form1.m_oWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in
> C:\prjname\trunk\GET\SAPSO\Form1.cs:line 103    at
> System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
> at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
> argument)
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
> SAPSO.CIP.ProcessOutput(System.DateTime, System.DateTime) in CIP.cs
> SAPSO.Form1.m_oWorker_DoWork(object, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) in Form1.cs
> [External Code]

Comment: OK, the JSON shown in your question is malformed (incorrect character escaping).  If you upload it to https://jsonlint.com/, you will get an error `Error: Parse error on line 4`.  You're not going to be able to deserialize that JSON using System.Text.Json or any other .NET JSON serializer.  Can you confirm that the JSON shown in your question is the actual JSON returned by the web service?  If so, you will need to contact the maintainers of the web service and have then fix their service to return well-formed JSON.

Comment: From the traceback it's clear that `GetDetailOutputs` returns `null` so `output.Count()` throws a `NulLReferenceException`.  If the web service can legitimately return a `null` then you need to check for it by testing `if (output == null || output.Count < 1)`.  But more likely the null return is caused by the malformed JSON -- somewhere in `client.ExecuteAsync<List<DetailOutput>>(request)` an exception is thrown which is swallowed and ignored.  Try breaking on first-chance exceptions in Visual Studio to find out where.

Comment: @dbc I also included a if ourput is null trapping but I'm so lost i really can't see why im getting null value. I edited some of the details on my json output due to some confidentially at my work hope you understand.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `client.ExecuteAsync<List<DetailOutput>>(request)` is returning `null` for the JSON shown?  If so, I don't know why that might happen, you need someone with more experience with RestSharp.  So, you should edit your question down to include only the RestSharp problem.  I.e. change the title to say e.g. *Why does RestClient.ExecuteAsync<List<T>>() return null for a JSON response that is an array?*, then edit your question to include just the code required to reproduce the problem, i.e. a [mcve].  Hopefully that will attract some RestSharp experts.

Comment: @dbc Thank you for suggestion. Im thinking is showing my stored procedure will help identify the problem or not? Thank you.

Comment: What's the response content (`RestResponse.Content`)? It looks like the fields that you expect to be `DateTime` aren't deserialized properly as they only contain the date. If System.Text.Json serializer fails to deserialize one property, it returns the whole object as null.